# adding font awesome icon to css panel

Tags: css

I have this CSS3 based panel that slides out vertically. How can I add a 2x fontawesome icon or any icon to the close /open panel button, which will display one icon for open and another  close icon for close?really appreciate your help.

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  word-spacing:-2px;
}

h1 {
  font-size:40px;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#191919;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

h2 {
  font-weight:normal;
  font-size:20px;
  color:#888;
  padding:5px 0;
}

.message {
  background:#181818;
  color:#FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: -250px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: top 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.message h1 {
  color:#FFF;
}

#toggle {
  position:absolute;
  appearance:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  left:-100%;
  top:-100%;
}

#toggle + label {
  position:absolute;
  cursor:pointer;
  padding:10px;
  background: #26ae90;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  color: #FFF;
  line-height:20px;
  font-size:12px;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin:20px 50px;
  transition:all 500ms ease;
}

#toggle + label:after {
  content:"Open" 
}

.container {
  transition: margin 300ms cubic-bezier(0.17, 0.04, 0.03, 0.94);
  padding:5em 3em;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .message {
  top: 0;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .container {
  margin-top: 250px;
}

#toggle:checked + label {
  background:#dd6149;
}

#toggle:checked + label:after {
  content:"Close"
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle"/>
<label for="toggle"></label>

<div class="container">
  <h1>Pure CSS3 Slide Down Toggle Demo</h1>
  <h2>Click the Open button to see content</h2>
</div>

<div class="message">
  <h1>Hidden message here</h1>
  <h2>CSS3 slide out menu</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It's using the `::after` pseudo class for the text on the button. You would need to change the font for that to fontawesome and put in your desired icon code into the content property. Look for the words 'open' and 'close' in the CSS to find the definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

Open:

```
#toggle + label:before {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content:"\f054";
}
#toggle + label:after {
  content:"Open"        
}
```

Close:

```
#toggle:checked + label:before{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    content:"\f0c9";
}
#toggle:checked + label:after {
  content:"Close"
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/z57b2e2c/1/

Comment: thank you.. i am noticing for close there no icon showing up. and is there away to show the icons at 2x or 3x size

Comment: Making the icon bigger is just adding the font-size property to it:
`font-size:28px;`, see my updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z57b2e2c/3/

If you want to find the right icon to use, look here:
http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/